# adding dynamically popup with enhanced content

Tags: jquery-mobile

I'm trying to dynamically add a popup to my page, whith nice JQM content (buttons, etc). The popup is added, but no styles applied.

Here's the code (it's not so long, so I copied here):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>  </head>
  <body>
    <div id='page' data-role='page'>

      <div data-role='header'>
        <h1> Header </h1>
      </div>

      <div data-role='content'>
        <p>Code sample</p>
        <a id='add' data-role='button'> Add popup </a>
        <a href='#popup' data-role='button' data-rel='popup'> Show dynamic popup </a>
        <a href='#popup2' data-role='button' data-rel='popup'> Show static popup </a>

      </div>
      <div id="popup2" data-role='popup'>
        <div data-role="header"> 
          <h1>Popup Header</h1> 
        </div>
        <div data-role="content"> 
          <p>Some content</p> 
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
    <script>
      $(document).ready( function(){
        $('#add').bind( 'click', function(ev){
          var
            page = $('#page');
          var 
              popup = $('<div id="popup" data-role="popup"></div>').appendTo( page )
            , header = $('<div data-role="header"> <h1>Popup Header</h1> </div>').appendTo( popup )
            , content = $('<div data-role="content"> <p>Some content</p> </div>').appendTo( popup );
          popup.popup();
        });
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

there's a [JsBin](http://jsbin.com/orehuv/1/) version, to play around with it.

So if I click to the **Show static popup** it displays the header nicely, but If I click **Add popup**, than show this newly added popup with **Show dynamic popup** the content of the popup looks differently.(using chrome)

So the question is: How can I enchanced the dynamically added popup content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to repaint the dynamically added content. To do this add `page.page('destroy').page();` after `popup.popup();`.

working example: http://jsbin.com/orehuv/3/

Comment: Nice. thx. What do you think, is it logical? My opinion is that `popup()` should enhance the content, but maybe I'm wrong, just started playing with JQM.

Comment: actually something like this `page.html('<div id="popup" data-role="popup"></div>').trigger('refresh');` should also work but in this case I don't know why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 6):

I found the solution, you can insert the popup in the same level as content, for ex.

```
<div data-role="page" >
  <div data-role="content" ></div>
  <div data-role="popup"></div>
</div>
```

Well with this way the popup function is good, but when you insert code for example from ajax request you have to insert the popup in the page and recall the method popup of the component.

ex .js file in the ajax call (the response is only the code of popup):

```
$('#page').append(response).trigger('create');

$("#popup").popup();
```

Remember that when you declare some popup in the principal page and it is not the same level as content. JQM automatically puts the popup in this place and it doesn't generate a problem.